# Delete from JSON nested dictionary in list value by iteration

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have JSON file 'json_HW.json' in which I have this format JSON:

```json
{
  "news": [
    {
      "content": "Prices on gasoline have soared on 40%",
      "city": "Minsk",
      "news_date_and_time": "21/03/2022"
    },
    {
      "content": "European shares fall on weak earnings",
      "city": "Minsk",
      "news_date_and_time": "19/03/2022"
    }
  ],
  "ad": [
    {
      "content": "Rent a flat in the center of Brest for a month",
      "city": "Brest",
      "days": 15,
      "ad_start_date": "15/03/2022"
    },
    {
      "content": "Sell a bookshelf",
      "city": "Mogilev",
      "days": 7,
      "ad_start_date": "20/03/2022"
    }
  ],
  "coupon": [
    {
      "content": "BIG sales up to 50%!",
      "city": "Grodno",
      "days": 5,
      "shop": "Marko",
      "coupon_start_date": "17/03/2022"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to delete **field_name** and **field_value** with their keys when I reach them until the whole information in the file is deleted. When there is no information in the file, I need to delete the file itself

The code I have

```py
data = json.load(open('json_HW.json'))  

for category, posts in data.items():
    for post in posts:
        for field_name, field_value in post.items():
            del field_name, field_value
            print(data)
```

But the variable data doesn't change when I delete  and delete doesn't work. If it worked I could rewrite my JSON

Comment: you're code seems to have some errors, you load `data`, but then you iterate a different variable `test_data`, and then print `data` inside the loop instead of at the end

Comment: @JayMody I changed and it still doesn't work

Comment: @JayMody I print the loop inside to see whether the variable changes or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are deleting the key and the value, after extracting them from the dictionary,
that doesn't affect the dictionary. What you should do is delete the dictionary entry:

```py
import json
import os

file_name = 'json_HW.json'
data = json.load(open(file_name))  

for category in list(data.keys()):
    posts = data[category]
    elem_indices = []
    for idx, post in enumerate(posts):
        for field_name in list(post.keys()):
            del post[field_name]
        if not post:
            elem_indices.insert(0, idx)  # so you get reverse order
    for idx in elem_indices:
        del posts[idx] 
    if not posts:
        del data[category]

print(data)           

if not data:
    print('deleting', file_name)
    os.unlink(file_name)
```

which gives:

```
{}
deleting json_HW.json
```

Note that the `list()` is necessary, `post.keys()` is a generator and
you cannot change the dict while you are iterating over its keys (or items or values).

Comment: Thank you, could you help me, how to delete the whole file from the directory  if we have this result

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delete key-value from dictionary, you can use del post[key].
but i don't think it works for iteration, cause dictionary size keeps changing.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-remove-a-key-from-dictionary/